# EditText with only digits. No Decimal Point

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to have an EditText which only allows numeric inputs. It should not allow even decimal point (.) in the field.

tried

```
<EditText
.....
android:digits="0123456789"
android:inputType="number"
android:maxLength="4"
.....
/>
```

But it still accepts decimal point. Any solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
  android:inputType="number"
  android:maxLength="4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

```
android:inputType="number|none"
android:maxLength="3"
android:digits="0123456789"
```